# Unable to access variable that is declared in GLSurfaceview class from Activity class without static

Tags: java, android, variables, static, android-activity

I have a GLRendering class which has a variable like so:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

int width;

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

//I know these values are being set here correctly here to the devices width and height
//Confirmed using Logging

this.width = width;
this.height = height;


}


}
```

In my Activity class I am creating an instance of my GLSurfaceView class and attempting to get the value of width via the object like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView myView;
MyGLRenderer render;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Request full screen

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    myView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    render = new MyGLRenderer(myView);

    setContentView(myView);
}
```

I have an inner class in my Activity class and it is from this class's onTouchEvent() method that I need to access this 'width' variable, like so:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

Log.v("Testing","Value of width is: "+render.width)
```

When I Log out the value from my onTouchEvent() method, it returns 0.  Why?  I know it's not 0 and is in fact the width of device's screen.

If I change the declaration of the 'width' variable in my MyGLSurfaceView class to *static* then it works fine, but the reason I'm creating an instance of MyGLSurfaceView class in my Activity class is because I don't want to use static.  I want to access it without using static.

I've also tried using a getter method and I get the same result.

Please could someone help me understand this behaviour and how to get 'round it? Thanks

Comment: It seems like onSurfaceChanged is never called, or called with a width equals to 0. Are you sure that onSurfaceCHanged is called?

Comment: Hi @ZouZou As stated above, if I declare the variable as static, it works fine.  Also, I am loading all of my resources (graphics, sound etc) in my onSurfaceChanged() method and the game runs fine, so it's is 100% defintately being called and running. Without Static, it is only returning the initial value of the width variable.  If I set it to 100 like int width = 100; then it will always return 100; but if I log it straight out from the onSurfaceChanged method, it will log out the correct value. :-)

Comment: Do you run your app on an emulator or real device ?

Comment: is the onTouchEvent in MyGLSurfaceView? if yes, then how are u accessing the render object in onTouchEvent of MyGLSurfaceView. Are u making the new object of MyGLRenderer as render der?

Comment: @bakriOnFire, yes onTouchEvent() is in MyGLSurfaceView, which is an inner class of MainActivity class, thus  has access to objects created in MainActivity.  Also, yes, I am creating a new MyGLRenderer object called 'renderer' as you can see from my code above.  ZouZou, testing on a real device - thanks

Comment: can u write **render = new MyGLRenderer(myView);** after setContentView(myView) and check.

Comment: Same problem @bakriOnFire :-(

Comment: Sounds to me like you are creating more than one renderer instance. One is effectively used to render the View, this one updates the width property correctly. When you try to get the width property, you seem to access another instance that has not updated the width. That's why it works when the property is static - multiple instances share the same variable. Ensure that you do not create more than one renderer instance.

Comment: Hi @SimonSays, thanks. Within this class, I am definately only creating one instance of MyGLRenderer. I am creating another instance of it (with a different name) but this is in a completely different class. Any idea how I can access this as an Instance Variable?  Thanks.

Comment: There are only two possibilities why you are getting zero when accessing the width property. 1. as i wrote before: you are accessing a wrong instance or 2. the property is indeed zero. So add some logging to your code. I would log the construction of the renderer class as well as any change to the width property. That should help you to find the problem. You could add and log a unique UUID to the renderer, so you always know what instance the log entry comes from.

Comment: @SimonSays, Could you put the gist of your comments into an answer, as I think you're right.  I will accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comments:

There are only two possibilities why you are getting zero when accessing the width property. 1. as i wrote in the comment before: you are accessing a wrong instance or 2. the property is indeed zero. So add some logging to your code. I would log the construction of the renderer class as well as any change to the width property. That should help you to find the problem. You could add and log a unique UUID to the renderer, so you always know what instance the log entry comes from.

Comment: Cheers, you were right, I had to use the renderer object that was already created so instead of using: new setRenderer(MyGLRenderer(this)); I moved my 'renderer = new MyGLRenderer(); to the MyGLSurfaceView constructor and then just set it like so: setRenderer(renderer), then I was able to use that renderer object to access the variables.  Thanks!